# No Numbering Part but section part

Tags: sectioning, parts

I write a report and I don't want to have a part but section...

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\title{Rapport unité d'enseigement libre : ASTEP}
\author{Agnès VIEL \& Jean KELLENS}
\date{Vendredi 17 Janvier}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Le choix}

\end{document}
```

I have 0.1.1

but I want 1.1

I don't find the way to remove the part numbering

Thanks for the answering

Comment: Hello, could you provide an MWE (minimal working example) of your report? So that we can provide a better solution

Comment: I just wrote the function

Comment: We need to know which document class you use, which related packages, &c. This is not an example, only a snippet.

Comment: You have all my code

Comment: In `1.1` what is the first 1?

Comment: it's section the first 1, because I just want section and subsection

Comment: The 0 is not from the part, it's from the chapter.  If you're not planning on chapters in your report, is there a reason that you're using the report class?

Answer (score 1):

We can get the output, by using the below macro:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
```

Place macro above the `\begin{document}` line.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's work

Comment: could you please upvote to the answer